# How to add backslashes to timecode string in python 2.7 in windows and osx

Tags: python, regex, ffmpeg, timecodes

To create a  burnt in timecode in ffmpeg, two escaping backslashes are required on the command line as so:

```
00\\:00\\:00\\:00
```

Using ffprobe to find the starting timecode produces the following output with a subprocess_output

```
00:00:00:00\n
```

I am using `rstrip()` to remove the new line, but how can I create a new variable that I can pass to ffmpeg's filter chain that will add those escaping backslashes?

I ultimately need my commandline to expand to something like this:

```
-vf 'drawtext=fontfile=/Library/Fonts/Tuffy.ttf:fontcolor=white:timecode=00\\:00\\:00\\:00:rate=25:boxcolor=0x000000AA:box=1:fontsize=40:x=360-text_w/2:y=405'
```

though of course in my script, it will just contain

```
timecode=%s
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using `replace` function you can be able to do that and after use `os.system` to execute the program.

```
In[4]: a = '00:00:00:00\n'
In[5]: a
Out[5]: '00:00:00:00\n'
In[6]: a = r'00:00:00:00\n'
In[7]: b = 'drawtext=fontfile' \
    '=/Library/Fonts/Tuffy.ttf:fontcolor=white:' \
    'timecode=%s:rate=25:' \
    'boxcolor=0x000000AA:box=1:fontsize=40:x=360-    text_w/2:y=405'%a.replace(':', '\\:').replace('\n', '')
In[8]: b
Out[8]:'drawtext=fontfile=/Library/Fonts/Tuffy.ttf:fontcolor=white:timecode=00\\:00\\:00\\:00\\n:rate=25:boxcolor=0x000000AA:box=1:fontsize=40:x=360-    text_w/2:y=405'
```

Comment: Hi Alexis, that worked great. I altered a few things, such as changing %a.replace to %s.replace. I removed the r in front of line 6 as it didn't make a difference and I didn't really know what it did. Thanks so much for helping me out.